# Flask: Extend template before rendering

Tags: flask

I want to have pluggable modules for my Flask application. Some modules can extend the UI. For such extensions I have blocks like `{% block extension1 %}` in my base template. The idea is to implement these blocks in separate template files that belong to the module.

Now it's a question - how to instruct main request handler to extend its template with module's one? I figure it can be done in `app.after_request()` method. But I haven't found any way to extend the template with the part from another file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be my solution isn't the best one but that's what I've come with.

base.html:

```
...
      {% if extension_1 %}
        {% include extension_1 ignore missing %}
      {% endif %}
...
```

module.py:

```
    @app.before_request
    def init_module():
        app.jinja_env.globals.update(extension_1='module.jinja')
```

module.jinja:

```
some content here
```

So when `extension_1` is defined the appropriate template is included.

I didn't handle conflict resolution when several modules define `extension_1` simultaneously. But I'll come to it when the need arises.